# Can there be two relationships between two tables?

Tags: mysql, database-design

There are two tables: EMPLOYER and EMPLOYEE. Since each EMPLOYEE is assigned to one EMPLOYER there's 1:N relationship between them - simple stuff.
But I also want to be able to model a situation where each EMPLOYER may be able to choose his **one** favorite EMPLOYEE (he might as well choose none).

So should I:
1. Add a second 1:1 relationship between those tables - this way EMPLOYER would also contain EMPLOYEE_id_FK. **Is having two relationship between two tables even allowed?**
2. Add a third table FAV identified by two primary, unique keys - EMPLOYER_ID and EMPLOYEE_ID? This way I would be sure each employer could only have one favorite employee and also each employee may be chosen as a fav only by one employee - which is exactly what I wanted.

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to have four table. One employee table, one employer table, a table to relate employee to employer (who says an employee can't work for two employers), and finally a table to relate an employer to their favorite employee.

EDIT: Yes, of course there can be two relationships between the same two tables.

Comment: "there can be two relationships between the same two tables" -- but this requires deferrable foreign key constraints, which are not available in MySQL.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can do it with 'joining tables', basically as I suggested in my answer. That requires nothing fancy.

Comment: Well, yeah, using a 3rd table. But not with only two tables. ;-)

Comment: Haha, yea, not with just two tables.

Comment: @Nik - can you describe the table that would store info about that favorite employees?
In my case an employer can only have one fav employee and an employee can only be favored by one employer (yea, I know it sounds silly, but it's not really about employees and employers..) - then I suppose it should look like this:
FAV (id_employer, id_employee, PRIMARY(id_employer, id_employee), UNIQUE(id_employer), UNIQUE(id_employee).
Does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense. That's exactly how I'd do it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an extra table (i.e. four tables instead of three) or to add some kind of `is_preferred` flag in the employer2employee table).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is allowed. You can have as many FKs as you like.

btw: It is a 1:N relationship, not 1:1. And when I would model this it both would be N:M relationships since one Employee can have more than one Employer.

Answer (score 0):

@Nik is right, you could have an employee with two employers, however, an employee can have only one favorite i am guessing, so you only need the FK relationship where Employer is the primary for the FavoriteEmp field in Employee.

Comment: That's true, but it's not a good design. You have to keep the future in mind. Maybe an employer would want two favorites in the future, or favorite employee evolves into simply really good employees.

Comment: @Nik, I don't disagree with that, but at the same time you can't be a boyscout in every situation, and be prepared for everything.  You have requirements and you create the best and most efficient design, leveraging both to present a product that satisfies FRS.

Comment: Absolutely, but this is hardly anything truly extra.

Comment: Ok, for the sake of simplicity I assumed that an Employee can only have one Emplyer. But my question remains, can choosing favorite be accomplish with just two tables? Is this correct:  EMPLOYER (
id (PK),
id_fav_employee(FK)
)

EMPLOYEE(
id (PK)
id_employee (FK)
)

Comment: @Matt, no, you want each employee to have a favorite employer.  This gives you Employee with minimum fields of Id, EmployerId, Name, FavoriteEmployerId.  The Employer table with minimum fields is Id, Name.  FavoriteEmployerId and EmployerId would be a FK relationship to the Employer table.