# Database design: Many to Many relation between tow table in tow different places

Tags: database-design

I have this database in it I can put seats into sections inside the hall for an event.

- in one part of my database, the section, and the event table have many to many relations in this relation I define the price for each section for this event.
- in another place, I have another relation between section and event tables to define seats for a section and event.

I didn't want to put them in one relation because I didn't want to define price on the level of seats.

My question: is it ok to have a relation between two tables in tow different places?

I put below my database image

[image]

Comment: Hi. Comments on downvotes are not required & everybody knows everybody wants one--except posters that retaliatorily downvote downvoters who comment. The implicit comment is the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please read [ask] & lots of [tag:database-design] questions like yours to see comments & answers & improvement edits. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework': Give the method/textbook you are following & show steps following it. Explain what you are certain about & why & why you think the dubious parts are dubious. "Is this valid" is too broad--an answer is a  bespoke tutorial.

Comment: I rephrased my question to be more clear.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: PS "Give the method/textbook you are following & show steps following it." What does your question have to do with what you were told to do? If what you are doing follows what you are told, it is ok. If it doesn't, why are you doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can there be two relationships between two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300059/can-there-be-two-relationships-between-two-tables)